# How to remap IPs visible from local machine to IPs visible from a machine I have SSH access to?

Tags: tunneling, networking, linux-networking, windows

I'm so far out of my depth I don't even know what to google for.

There's a server I can connect to via SSH. Via that server I can access other server on its subnet via SSH. What I want to do is be able to access the machines that server has access to directly. Say the server IP is 192.168.7.7 and is the only one in the 192.168.x.x range I have access to. I'd like to configure things in such a way that when I to access say 192.168.7.100 on my machine, the connection will go through an SSH tunnel I open to 192.168.7.7 and out to 192.168.7.100. I would like this to work for any port if at all possible.

I know I can set an HTTP proxy and even a SOCKS proxy, but I'm wondering is there is a way to actually remap some of the IP my machine sees to IP only visible from the remote machine.

What would this configuration be called? IS this NAT, VPN, IP2IP or something else? How can I set up this on a Windows client box that connects via SSH to a Linux box? Sounds to me like I need to set up some kind of filtering on the network driver or possibly a virtual NIC, but I'm not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be a VPN server on the machine you use as a tunneling gateway now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. However, I don't really need another level of encryption, the SSH connection gives me all I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can either go with a VPN solution or a SOCKS proxy, otherwise I cannot think of anything else that would give you the flexibility. But I would say, for your purpose a ssh connection with socks proxy like

```
ssh -v -N -D 1080 user@host
```

and then the new sessions with SOCKS proxy is probably easier then setting up a whole VPN for it.